# Antlr visitor method is never called

Tags: antlr, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I tried to create a simple language, which can evaluate if/else if/else statements and some arithmetic operations with predefined constans. The definition is the following:

```
grammar test;

ifStatement
:
    ifPart elseIfPart* elsePart
;

ifPart
:
    'if (' logicalExpression ') then ' retVal=basicElement
;

elseIfPart
:
    ' else if (' logicalExpression ') then ' retVal=basicElement
;

elsePart
:
    ' else ' retVal=basicElement
;

logicalExpression 
:
    logicalExpression ' and ' logicalExpression #andLogicalExpression
    |logicalExpression ' or ' logicalExpression #orLogicalExpression
    | compareExpression #compareLogicalExpression
    | '(' logicalExpression ')' #parensLogicalExpression
;

compareExpression
:
    basicElement '' basicElement #gt
    | basicElement '=' basicElement #eq
;


basicElement
:
    operation
    | atomicElement
;

operation
:
    operation op=('*'|'/') operation #mulDiv |
    operation op=('+'|'-') operation #addSub |
    atomicElement #atomic |
    '(' operation ')' #operationParens
;

atomicElement
:
    INT #decimal
    | 'resVal1' #reservedVariable
    | 'resVal2' #reservedVariable
;

INT
:
    [-]?[0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)? 
;

WS
:
    [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

I generated a Visitor and a created a test sentence, which is the following:

```
    if (3+3=6 or 12*3=37) then 10*10 else 4+1
```

It returns 5, which is wrong. After some debugging I saw that the visitOrLogicalExpression method is never called, instead of it the visitCompareLogicalExpression is called two times. What is wrong with my language definition?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Do not you get at least warnings for your grammar? Your logicalExpression seems wrong (left-recursive without guards).

Comment: Tokens like this `' else if ('` are just plain wrong. That must be 3 tokens: `'else'`, `'if'` and `'('`.

Comment: @GáborBakos Antlr4 let you use directly left-recursive rules (left-recursion within only one rule).

Comment: @Mephy Cool. I was unaware of it. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language definition was ok. I could fix the mentioned problem by modifying the `Visitor` class.

In the `visitIfPart` and `visitElseIfPart` methods (which process the subtrees of the `if` and `else if` nodes) I had to change the `visitChildren(ctx.logicalExpression())` method to `visitLogicalExpression(ctx.logicalExpression())`, thus my code was able to catch the compound logical expressions.